# ember-cli How to set default value from form select?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My template:

```
<select name="lang" id="lang" onchange={{action "selectOption" value="target.value"}}>
    <option value="">--Choose--</option>
    {{#each model as |lang|}}
    <option value="{{lang.url}}">{{lang.title}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

`lang.url` has one of the values: `['php', 'javascript', ...]`

My Controller:

```
lang: 'php', //this is not working, I am thinking of something like lang.url or lang.get('url') but looks like it is still not right ..
actions: {
selectOption: function(option) { 
  this.set("lang", option);
}
```

How can I set the default value of select to php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `true` to the selected option's `selected` attribute. Something like this:

```
<option value="{{lang.url}}" selected={{eq lang.url lang}}>{{lang.title}}</option>
```

[`eq helper`](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers/blob/master/addon/helpers/equal.js) can be found here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, `lang` property in controller and in each block helper refers to different context is the problem.either you need to change lang property in controller to some other property name

> application.js -> route

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return [{'url':'phpurl','title':'phptitle'},{'url':'javascripturl','title':'javascripttitle'}];
  }
});
```

> application.js -> controller

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  lang: 'phpurl', 
    actions: {
        selectOption: function(option) {
      console.log(option);
        this.set("lang", option);
        }
  }
});
```

> application.hbs ->template file

```
<select name="lang" id="lang" onchange={{action "selectOption" value="target.value"}}>
    <option value="">--Choose--</option>
    {{#each model as |item|}}
    <option value="{{item.url}}" selected={{eq item.url lang}}>{{item.title}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>

{{outlet}}
```

Working sample [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f0e54b5486e1279f6c08f46c716a833a?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)